# Excel Formatted Table Sync with Range Data for Powe BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, excel-tables

I am working on link up Power BI and Excel. As far as I know, Power BI can only link data from Excel via formatted table.
I have Excel range data, thinking of to create another formatted table that link to the Excel range data.
How can I dynamically resize the formatted table (add row) when range data added new row of data.

Answer (score 2):

That's a misconception. You can also import from sheets. Have a look into the official documentation before making wrong assumptions:

[Get data from Excel workbook files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-excel-workbook-files)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. From the section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-excel-workbook-files#workbooks-with-ranges-or-tables-of-data, if my understanding is correct, the range data has to be converted to formatted table.

Comment: Wrong. Read again - and try for yourself!